# What is the difference between a route and resource in New Router API?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I am trying to understand the difference between a `Route` and a `Resource`. The way I understand `Resource` helps to set sub paths of a `Route` object to another `Route` Object. But its unclear when i think of default name mapping happening for paths as well.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

> **Please Note that from 1.11.0 onwards, `this.route` is only used instead of `this.resource`. Source: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/routing/defining-your-routes/***

Have a look at this [post](http://darthdeus.github.com/blog/2013/02/01/ember-dot-js-router-and-template-naming-convention/) for a detailed explanation.

This is a rough summary of this post (i have modified a bit):

> Ever since the change to resource and route a lot of people are
>   confused about the meaning of the two and how they affect naming.
>   Here’s the difference:
>
> - resource - a thing (a model)
> - route - something to do with the thing

So this means a router using a route and resource might look like this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("posts", { path: "/" }, function() {
    this.route("new", { path: "/new" });
  });
  this.route("another", { path: "/another" });
});
```

This would result in the following routes being created/used:

- PostsRoute, PostsController, PostsView
- PostsIndexRoute, PostsIndexController, PostsIndexView
- PostsNewRoute, PostsNewController, PostsNewView
- AnotherRoute, AnotherController, AnotherView

As we see from this example, resource effect the naming of the Controllers,Routes and Views being used/created (The "new" route is treated as subordinate to "posts" resource). Cite from the original source (i modified it, because it was irritating as Patrick M correctly pointed out in the comments):

> This means whenever you create a resource it will create a brand new
>   namespace. That namespace is named after the
>   resource and all of the child routes will be inserted into it.

**Update: more complex example with nested resources**

Consider the following more complex example with multiple nested resources:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("posts", { path: "/" }, function() {
    this.route("new", { path: "/new" });
    this.resource("comments", { path: "/comments" }, function() {
      this.route("new", { path: "/new" });
    });
  });
  this.route("another", { path: "/another" });
});
```

In this case the resource `comments` creates a brand new namespace. This means the resulting routes in this case will be the following. **As you can see the Route, Controller and View for the comments resource are not prefixed with the name of the parent route.** That means nesting a resource within another resource resets the namespace (= creates a new namespace).

- PostsRoute, PostsController, PostsView
- PostsIndexRoute, PostsIndexController, PostsIndexView
- PostsNewRoute, PostsNewController, PostsNewView
- **CommentsRoute, CommentsController, CommentsView**
- **CommentsNewRoute, CommentsNewController, CommentsNewView**
- AnotherRoute, AnotherController, AnotherView

This behaviour is also explained in the [Ember Docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_nested-resources).

Comment: This should be clearer in the Ember guides. I was certainly confused by this concept at first.

Comment: Excellent summary of an excellent post. But the last quote you include doesn't make sense: `That namespace will have an " which [...]`. What does the `"` mean? Is it just a placeholder for Route | Controller | View?

Comment: Hey Patrick, thanks for pointing that out. I could not make a clue out of it anymore. Therefore i added more complex example with nested resources. I think this cite referred to this scenario.

Comment: That is much clearer. Thanks for the extra example, mavilein.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is the difference (if any) between your example and this: `App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("posts", { path: "/" }, function() {
    this.route("new");
    this.route("comments"}, function() {
      this.route("new");
    });
  });
  this.route("another", { path: "/another" });
});`

Comment: @TimoLehto: I think your approach probably does not even work (only use routes, no resources). As far as i remember you are not allowed to nest beneath routes. You are only allowed to nest beneath resources.

Comment: @mavilein Sure you can. You used to not be able to create nested routes, but it's totally legit nowadays. Just somewhat poorly documented. So that's why I ask. To bring this answer up-to-date with the way things work presently.

Comment: @TimoLehto I am not very up to date with Ember. Then it may be that a route with nested childs is the same as a resource. The only thing i would check then wether nested routes have the same behavior regarding the namespaces. -> Does each route with children reset the namespace?

Comment: Hey, just wanted to comment that currently the only difference between `this.resource` and `this.route` is that the first resets the namespace, while the latter doesn't. Everything else is the same. From what I understand, `this.resource` is to be deprecated, so **use `this.route`**.

Comment: yes..since 1.11.0 this.route is only used rather this.resource