# How to namespace an ember route in Ember 1.11.0

Tags: ember.js

My understanding is that Ember 1.11.0 deprecated `resource` in a router in favor of only using `route`.  Per what I've read, the difference between the two was that a `resource` created a namespace. See: [What is the difference between a route and resource in New Router API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973556/what-is-the-difference-between-a-route-and-resource-in-new-router-api)

So the question is how do I namespace a route so that, in the example below, my comments Route, Controller, and View are not prefixed with 'Posts'?

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("posts", { path: "/" }, function() {
    this.route("new", { path: "/new" });
    this.route("comments", { path: "/comments" }, function() {
      this.route("new", { path: "/new" });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing `resetNamespace: true` to the route like

```
this.route("comments", { path: "/comments", resetNamespace: true }, function() {
  this.route("new", { path: "/new" });
});
```

Comment: While this is the easiest way to get rid of `this.resource`, `resetNamespace` is technically a private API so there's no guarantee that it'll stick around, which may or may not be better than sticking with `this.resource` which is officially deprecated.

Comment: @Ahmad `resetNamespace` is a public API now. Refer to this [ember documentation](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_resetting-nested-route-namespace). 
and this [issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11251)

Comment: @Ahmad ohh.. I didn't notice. ha ha.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `resetNamespace` option for a route, something like this:

```
this.route('posts', {}, function() {
  this.route('comments', {resetNamespace: true});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there's no way of doing that using the public API without using `this.resource`, which is officially deprecated and slated for removal in Ember 2.0. Using `resetNamespace` is not officially supported as it is a private API so, technically, it may be removed at any time without warning.

The official solution to this problem is to refactor your application to accept that the Comments Routes and Templates are under Posts.

Comment: Hopefully they expose some kind of public API for it in the future as an app with deeply nested routes (or even 3 levels of nesting) can end up with long and sometimes odd class names without it.

Comment: @cbonser it's very likely that they will https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11251